# Enlarege the images output from ob-ipython

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I read such an example in [10 minutes in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html)

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results raw drawer
 ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000),
                index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
 ts = ts.cumsum()
 ts.plot()
#+end_src
```

get the result:

[image]

The image displayed is very tiny, how could enlarge the it by modifying the ipython's configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double the size of images output from ob-ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194625/double-the-size-of-images-output-from-ob-ipython)